# TSQL - get column result to be read as multiple strings for "in" operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use the following select as the "from" for an update of 100k + records

```
--select *
from [Node-4-127].location [l] 
inner join [Node-4-127 ].zone [z] 
on l.[address.zip] in (substring (replace (z.zips, '*',        ''', '''),4, 4000))
```

a sample row result is:

```
'91301', '91320', '91361', '91362', '91377', '91358', '91360',
```

I've wrapped that result in parenthesis for the "in", but it's treating the entire result as 1 string as opposed to treating each quoted result as a separate string within the parenthesis.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, use Jeff Moden's  CSV splitter from my [answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns/72298#72298)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH E1(N) AS (
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
       ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
            SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() 
                                                        OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just
                     -- once for each delimiter)
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL
            SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
        ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
            SELECT s.N1,
                   ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
            FROM cteStart s
        )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final
     -- element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
go
```

to separate the distinct ZIP codes into separate entries.

Then you can simply join against the result instead of dynamically creating the IN criteria. This is also likely to be more efficient as well.